# How to ignore warnings using Net::Telnet::Cisco in Perl 5.8?

Tags: perl, perl5.8

I installed. Net::telnet::cisco module in Perl 5.8 and trying to do following:

```
my $session = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(Host=>'192.168.1.1',Ignore_warnings=>1);
```

But this doesn't seem to work and gives following error:

```
bad named parameter "Ignore_warnings" given to Net::Telnet::Cisco::new()
```

Any ideas what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Separate it out:

```
my $session = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(Host => $host);
$session->ignore_warnings(1);
```

Looks like a bug in NTC to me.  I expect it's supposed to remove its parameters from the list before calling SUPER::new.

Comment: Tried that also...here's the error I get after that: Net::Telnet::Cisco=GLOB(0x317c88) is an [unexpected] object